# Differentiation always easy?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

There are many examples of real functions admitting antiderivatives (since e.g. continuous), but where computing a concrete antiderivative is a seriously hard problem even if an elementary one exists.

What about differentiation? My experience is that the basic rules of calculus along with term-by-term differentiantion of power series make differentiation a just-do-it kind of problem for virtually all everyday kinds of functions. In fact, if we add the limit exchange trick for uniformly convergent sequence of derivatives, I cannot think of any examples, where finding a closed form for $f'$, given a closed form for $f$, is not a mechanical task.

So the question is: are there any examples of real functions $f$, such that

(1) $f$ is given in "nice" closed form $f(x)=\ldots$

(2) it is "relatively easy" to justify that $f$ is differentiable

(3) computing the derivative of $f$ is actually hard.

This isn't exactly a precise question, but there just might be a "know it when I see it" example.

Comment: Why require "relatively easy" in (2)? Anyway, all elementary functions have elementary derivatives. Beyond elementary functions and things constructed from them out of limits, it's not quite clear what computing the derivative means. Of course you can compute it numerically, but you can do that with antiderivatives too.

Comment: *Usually* the way to show that a function is differentiable is by computing its derivative!  Often that involves a bit of metacomputation, e.g. knowing how to differentiate sums/products/compositions, then expressing your function in terms of "elementary" ones (for which you know derivatives explicitly).  But you likely know all of this.  

I, too, would like to see a function that we know to be differentiable, but in some indirect way.

Comment: Indeed by "relatively easy" I mean "without directly computing the derivative", maybe this should be edited.

Comment: I suppose the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ might count — it's derivatives can't be written in any simpler form than simply "$\zeta'(s)$," "$\zeta''(s)$," etc. Though I'm not sure if this satisfies your first condition. For $s>1$, $\zeta(s)$ can be defined as $\frac1{1^s}+\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{3^s}+\dotsb$. (This definition doesn't converge for other values, but there is a way to define it for all $s\ne1$.)

Comment: This looked promising, but then I found this :-) https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Riemann_Zeta_Function

Comment: By the way, there _is_ an algorithm for computing the antiderivative of any elementary function (or proving that one doesn't exist): The [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm). Technically, it's only a semi-algorithm, since one of its steps involves seeing if certain expressions are equivalent to zero, which apparently is a [hard problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_problem). (Also, I think it's the sort of algorithm that can only really be done on a computer.)

Comment: As far as _elementary functions_ go, you can always differentiate fairly easily. And, for functions of the form $\displaystyle\sum(\text{elementary stuff})$, I suppose you can always differentiate term-by-term (like for the zeta function).

Comment: I think in general you can only differentiate term by term if the partial sums of the term-by-term derivative converge uniformly (and Zeta does locally). And yes, I come to realize that the anology with antiderivatives was a bad one.

Comment: I saw this function a while ago, though I forget from where. What about something like $\Omega(x) = \min\{\theta \ge 0\ |\ \tan(x\theta) + \tan(x^2\theta) + \tan(x^3\theta) = 1\}$? I'm pretty sure it's differentiable on $\Bbb{R}_+$. Not sure if it satisfies the "simple" requirement though. Usually functions like this that are defined as the solution to equations that don't have elementary solutions are difficult if impossible to differentiate in closed form.

Comment: Functions like $\displaystyle f(z) = \sqrt{0 + \sqrt{z + \sqrt{2z^2 + \sqrt{3z^3 + \sqrt{4z^4 + \cdots}}}}}$ are very difficult to differentiate, but are differentiable everywhere in their domain. It can also be proven that it converges for all $z$ using the Herschfeld Theorem on Infinite Radicals (http://www.pballew.net/1935Herschfeld.pdf).

Comment: On second thought, you can derive an infinite series for the derivative of infinite radical functions inductively with relative ease. Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \sqrt{a_0(x) + \sqrt{a_1(x) + \sqrt{a_2(x) + \cdots}}} \\$, and define the *unravelling operator* or denesting operator as $\operatorname{U}_n\{f\} = \left(\operatorname{U}_{n-1}\{f\}\right)^2 - a_{n-1}(x)$ with $\operatorname{U}_0\{f\} = f$. Then $\displaystyle
\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{a_n'(x)}{2^n}\left(\prod_{k=0}^n{\operatorname{U}_n\{f\}}\right)^{-1}}
$

Answer (score 1):

I think one example you might be interested in is the [Cantor Ternary Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function). Recall that the [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) is formed by taking the unit interval $[0,1]$, then throwing away the middle third, then throwing away the middle thirds of each resulting interval, and doing so infinitely many times. The resulting set is the Cantor set.

You can read the exact definition of the function in the link but loosely speaking, it's obvious that the function is constant on the complement of the Cantor ternary set: the intervals you threw away. So clearly the function has zero derivative on these intervals. Less obvious is that the function is *not* differentiable at any point of the Cantor ternary set. On the other hand, the Cantor ternary set has *[measure zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics))*, so in a precise sense the function is differentiable almost everywhere. It's also continuous, which is not obvious! So it's an example of an *increasing*, *continuous* function whose derivative is 0 almost everywhere!

Comment: That's as far as my imaginations gets, too, but there is a huge difference between a function being differentiable and almost everywhere differentiable just like contnuous and almost everywhere continuous (=Riemann-integrable) are entirely different things.

Answer (score 0):

Given any function comprised of elementary compositions of base case elementary functions whose derivatives are known, i.e. starting with base case elementary functions and then making new functions through repeated application of addition, multiplication, and composition of functions, the standard rules of differentiation say that we can come up with an elementary formulation for the derivative provided derivatives are "known" for the base case functions. Thus, your only hope for an example is something like an exotic function whose definition we take as given, in terms of base case exotic functions that are acceptable, but whose derivative cannot be similarly expressed in terms of the collection of "accepted" base case exotic functions. But this seems a bit pedantic.